# Did Julius Caesar say: "Africa, I have grabbed you"?

Tags: roman-empire, africa, quotes, julius-caesar

Someone once told me that when Julius Caesar stepped off the boat onto the North African shore, he tripped and landed flat on his face, to which he then said (in an amazing comeback to onlookers trying hard not to laugh):

> "Africa, I have grabbed you."

What is the source (if any) for this story? Did it actually happen?

Comment: Just to note, "Africa" would mean a very different thing for Caesar than to us (what we call "Africa" he would probably call "Aethiopia").

Comment: @LuisHenrique and what they would call "Africa" we would probably call "Tunisia".

Comment: @LuísHenrique Actually, he was probably referring to the Roman province [Africa Proconsularis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa_(Roman_province)). In the Greco-Roman period, [Aethiopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aethiopia) generally referred to lands further south.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It apparently happened during Caesar's [campaign](http://classics.mit.edu/Caesar/african.html) against Scipio and Juba in 47BC, part of the wider [Roman Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar%27s_Civil_War) that was fought from 49–45BC. The story was recorded by [Suetonius](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/e/roman/texts/suetonius/12caesars/julius*.html) (Life of Julius Caesar: 59).

The quote, as it has come down to us from Suetonius, was:

> "teneo te," inquit, "Africa."

or

> "I hold you, Africa", he said.

Although amusing to modern readers, this would have been intended to turn an evil omen - stumbling while disembarking from the boat - into a more favourable one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sempaiscuba! I'm glad to know the story I heard actually has a source and is not something made up - it's a very humorous story (in my opinion) which is why I doubted it.

Comment: @ezra It seems his act was copied by [Guillaume le Bâtard](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a4NZYnOqKXYC&pg=PA42&dq=william+conqueror+fall+beach&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJlr6BwcvWAhXKJsAKHaaQDscQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=william%20conqueror%20fall%20beach&f=false) at the start of the Norman Conquest of England. :)

Comment: @ezra: He did say "veni, vidi, vici," so this would have been entirely in character.

Comment: @ezra, it may have been made up (ancient historians were not above embellishing their tales), but if so, it was made up *long* ago.

Comment: @Mark I've often wondered whether William of Malmesbury was familiar with Suetonius when he came to write about Guillaume le Bâtard coming ashore in 1066.

Comment: I believe the actual quote was

I tripped.
I gripped.
I quipped.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, correct quote is : "teneo te, Africa". 
In Suetone's text, it reads : "teneo te, inquit, Africa" 
but "inquit" (and note "inuit"), only means "he said".

Comment: Can you perhaps add a reference for this insight?

Answer (score 1):

This is very good question. Suetonius really wrote that Caesar said it. By the way, its position in [Suetonius' book](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/e/roman/texts/suetonius/12caesars/julius*.html) indicates that this statement is, according to Suetonius, a blasphemy and thus this idea does not serve to Caesar's honor.

<del>By other hand, Onasander describes in Strategikos the same situation and the same statement, but his story is about Scipio Africanus. Moreover, in some latin editions of Strategikos, there is the note that Suetone (Tranquillis) ascribed this story to Caesar.</del> (My mistake. I've read it, but not in Onasander)

Finally, Sextus Frontinus describes in Strategemata ([book I, part XII](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/L/Roman/Texts/Frontinus/Strategemata/1*.html#12)) both stories. Scipio Africanus said "plaudite milites, Africam oppressi" ("Applaude, soldiers, I'm crushing the Africa") and later, in similar situation, Caesar said "teneo te, terra mater" ("I'm holding you, mother Earth").

Comment: A clearer source would improve this answer.

Comment: @ezra I'm affraid that I've mentioned primary sources only. 

Suetone's De vita Ceasareum (given part, in English) is here: [https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Lives_of_the_Twelve_Caesars/Julius_Caesar#59]. 

Sextus Frontinus's Strategemata (given part, in Englist) is here: [http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Frontinus/Strategemata/1*.html#12] (I know, I've added this part after your note...). 

I've Onasander at home and, unfortunately, Czech translation...